# Ruby: Trying to dynamically define instance methods in class definition: Why does using define_method work but not alias_method?

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I have a class definition in which I want to alias several of its attribute methods with shorthand terms. e.g. "price" to "pr", and so forth:

The following implementation works:

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  ABBREVS = {:price=>:pr, :country=>:ct}
  ABBREVS.each_pair{|k,v| define_method(v){ self.send(k) } }
end
```

However, define_method seems too...heavy-handed, right? Shouldn't **alias_method** work as well?

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  ABBREVS = {:price=>:pr, :country=>:ct}
  ABBREVS.each_pair{|k,v| alias_method(v, k) }
end
```

When I do this, though, I get this kind of Class error:

```
NameError: undefined method `price' for class `Fruit'
```

Apparently, Ruby thinks I'm trying to alias a class method rather than an instance method. Am I just using alias_method wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? To purposely reduce readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you are trying to alias a method that hasn't been defined yet. I don't know the ins and outs of ActiveRecord but as the schema isn't defined in the code but in the DB I suspect the accessor methods aren't defined until the first time you hit the database to get the schema - which may well be after your `alias_method` calls.

But I don't think you should do this! Just type the longer names!

Comment: Just for context's sake, the abbreviations are for when I output this to JavaScript, as a way to minimize the client-side downloading while maintaining some kind of mapping with the database schema.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds like a lot of work and a lot of potential bugs - and much harder to debug code - for what I imagine (but wouldn't know without testing) must be a very small performance gain.